# display a message before (or after) a redirect javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display a message after or before a redirect. I looked around the site but I found only jquery and php but I can only use the normal java language. In particular I'm trying to use a div that could be good for me. The problem is that the redirect is on the server side (so I cannot call a javascript function or I cannot put a document.getElementByID). Can you help me? Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var middleware =  require('../middleware');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
var User = mongoose.model('User');
var config = require("../../config");
var session;

router.all('/', middleware.supportedMethods('GET, POST'));
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('login');
});
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var post = req.body;
    var query = User.where({userName : post.username});
    query.findOne(function(err, user){
        if (err) { return err}
        if (user) {
             user.isValidPassword(post.password, function(n, isMatch){
                if(isMatch) {
                    req.session.user_id = user._id;
                    res.redirect('/library?' + user._id);
                } else{

                    res.redirect('/login');
                }
             });
        }else{
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I would put my message on the res.redirect('/login') (both of them) with two different message. I don't know if I have to create a new page, identical, with a div message or I could find a better solution...

Comment: *"but I can only use the normal java language"* Java != JavaScript. Did you mean JavaScript?

Comment: what is "the normal java language"?

Comment: Yes yes. So sorry guys. I never use jquery but I saw that for this language normally there are $ signs. I put some questions before but people put me answers with this type of language. I don't want that other people lose time because I didn't specify enough the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to display a message after or before a redirect...The problem is that the redirect is on the server side (so I cannot call a javascript function or I cannot put a document.getElementByID).

Exactly. So you can't do that. Instead, you need to return a redirect to a page with your message on it, and then have *that* page continue on (after a period of time, or after a user action) to the ultimate destination (`/login` or whatever).

A **minimal** intermediary page might look like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Some Relevant Title</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"></meta><!-- Or whatever is appropriate -->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15; url=/login">
</head>
<body>
Message goes here. With the refresh above, the page will refresh after 15 seconds.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So it's the idea I thought about. I have to create an identical page with the messages I want to show. Is it right?

Comment: @pp94: Something like that. You could use a query string to pass a message ID and then have the page only show the message that matches the ID.

Comment: If one specific action causes your redirect you can display an `alert('message')` that requires user interaction to continue.

Comment: Yeah but as I specified I don't know how to use jquery (yes I know... it's strange). Well, I will do it... Thanks

Comment: I wrote here to see if there is a better solution but there is nothing of it. Thanks @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @pp94: Not sure what you mean about jQuery above, but neither my suggestion nor Pio's requires using jQuery.

Comment: so wait... what do you mean with "query message"?